# Paypal IPN Simulator (Different Sites, different results)

Tags: paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox

This is leading me into confusion only. After reading Paypal's documentation for Paypal IPN, I know how to get to the Simulator page and trigger an IPN test. Reading throughout PP's documentation, the page I am lead to is:
https://developer.paypal.com/developer/ipnSimulator/

Now, on my server side, I have used one of PP's Listenter example file in which I've implemented my own class to log everything I need into text files, and, I know that my IPN Listener is up, running and receiving requests from the IPN Simulator because I can see it all beeing logged.

Now the intriguing part is that, as I said before, i'm lead to the aforementioned page, which triggers an **INVALID** response from Paypal every single time I simulate a payment. Afters dozens of forums read, including SO, I have seen some people using https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/applications/ipn_simulator instead of the former one. 
If I use this latter URL, the simulation works without a hitch and I get the "VERIFIED" response, everytime. At this point, the question I cannot answer is "Why?". Why does this only works on the latter URL, and not on the URL that I am redirected to from within my paypal account, which is the one I think it was supposed to work from? And this constitutes by itself another problem. I cannot access this latter URL from anywhere within my paypal account, unless I manually enter it. You may question how did I get to this second URL. Well, I got it from other people's posts, otherwise I didn't even know it existed. So, right now I am completly lost and with this said,

1. Is there anyone that can explain me the difference from both URLs, and why is the second one not available inside my PP account?
2. If you can also explain me why the simulation works from the second URL only, that would be a bonus

**NOTE:** By the way, I've tried it and I know that in Live mode it works also, and I get the VERIFIED response.